# Unable to select sibling checkbox in CSS3

Tags: css

I'm using CSS3 selectors to produce a cross-browser solution for styling radio buttons. My solution has to be javascript free as well. Everything works except the radio button is not hidden - I'm unable to select it via `label~input`, although `input~label` works perfectly. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/CsMat/

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input id="click-1" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe" />
  <label for="click-1">Click me!</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {position:relative}
label ~ input {display:none}
input ~ label {padding:0 0 0 25px;}
label:before{border-radius:20px; background:blue; content:''; display:block; position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0; height:20px; width:20px;}
input:checked + label:before{background:red;}
```

Comment: The silbling selector only works when selecting the following sibling, not the preceeding one. You can select the label from the input but not the input from the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from my comment on the original question (you can't select the preceding sibling):

I see a lot of answers have being posted where you're simply hiding the radio button by using `display: none;` - DO NOT DO THIS!

This is bad for accessibility - you are removing the element in a way where it's not detected by screen readers and this is a NO-NO.

Instead, you should visually hide the element. It means many things such as offsetting the position of the input so it's off the screen and not visible or using the `clip` property to hide the element.

In your case, I would recommend this markup:

```
<div class="field">
    <input id="click-1" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe">
    <label for="click-1">Click me!</label>
</div><!-- .field -->
```

And your CSS would be:

```
/* This method, though more lines of code, visually hides the element from the page but keeps it in the DOM to be accessible by screen readers */
.field input[type=radio] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

.field input[type=radio] ~ label {
    /* Your label code here */
}
```

Read about why you shouldn't use `display: none;` here: http://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/

Shameless self plug: http://hieroishere.com/flatui/

Where I've used the bare basics to create visually appealing form elements.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Oh bother, I mis-read the description for 'general' and 'adjacent' selectors - I assumed general should go all around.

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd handle this is to class the containing div, and build your selector based on that:

HTML:

```
<div class="field easy-toggle">
  <input id="click-1" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe" />
  <label for="click-1">Click me!</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.easy-toggle input {
    opacity: 0.01;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999em;
}
```

The rationale here is that the containing element becomes the 'unit' of markup you're styling  - one or more classes on the unit tell everything else inside it how to display. It does adds an extra element, sure, but the amount of reusability and clarity it adds more than makes up for it.

The other thing going on here is that older Internet Explorers (8 and below, from memory), don't allow labels to trigger inputs that are display:none or visibility:hidden - you need to have them technically 'visible' in order for the label to be clickable (if you care about those browsers).

Comment: This is why I wanted to use the CSS3 selectors - as IE8 and before would not support them, the input would appear in place of the fancy-pants ones. This is essentially the method I'm using at current whilst looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

hi @Toby the idee is correct you have to use `[id=click-1]` and or `[for=click-1]`

**option 1:**

**the markup :**

```
    <div>
        <input id="click-1" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe" />
        <label for="click-1">Click me!</label>
    </div>
    <div>  
        <input id="click-2" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe" />
        <label for="click-2">Click me!</label>
    </div>
    <div>  


    <input id="click-3" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe" />
    <label for="click-3">Click me!</label>
</div>
```

**the style:**

```
div {position:relative;margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
input[type=radio] {display:none}
div label {padding:0 0 0 25px;}
label:before{border-radius:20px; background:blue; content:''; display:block; position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0; height:20px; width:20px; opacity:0.2}
input[id=click-1]:checked + label[for=click-1]:before{background:red!important;}
input[id=click-2]:checked + label[for=click-2]:before{background:black!important;}
input[id=click-3]:checked + label[for=click-3]:before{background:green!important;}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CsMat/3/

**option 2:**

**the markup:**

```
<div>
    <input id="click-1" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe" />
    <label for="click-1">Click me!</label>
</div>
<div>  
    <input id="click-2" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe" />
    <label for="click-2">Click me!</label>
</div>
<div>   
    <input id="click-3" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe" />
    <label for="click-3">Click me!</label>
</div>
```

**the style:**

```
div {position:relative;margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
input[type=radio] {display:none}
div label {padding:0 0 0 25px;}
label:before{border-radius:20px; background:blue; content:''; display:block; position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0; height:20px; width:20px; opacity:0.2}
input[id=click-1]:checked + label:before{background:red!important;}
input[id=click-2]:checked + label:before{background:black!important;}
input[id=click-3]:checked + label:before{background:green!important;}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CsMat/4/

**option 3:**

**the markup:**

```
<input id="click-1" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe" />
<input id="click-2" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe" />
<input id="click-3" type="radio" value="1" name="clickMe" />
<div>
    <label for="click-1">Click me!</label>
</div>
<div>  
    <label for="click-2">Click me!</label>
</div>
<div>   
    <label for="click-3">Click me!</label>
</div>
```

**the style:**

```
div {position:relative;margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
input[type=radio] {display:none}
div label {padding:0 0 0 25px;}
label:before{border-radius:20px; background:blue; content:''; display:block; position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0; height:20px; width:20px; opacity:0.2}
input[id=click-1]:checked ~ div label[for=click-1]:before{background:red!important;}
input[id=click-2]:checked ~ div label[for=click-2]:before{background:black!important;}
input[id=click-3]:checked ~ div label[for=click-3]:before{background:green!important;}
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/CsMat/2/

Comment: The functionality worked exactly as I wanted in my example, all I needed was to select the preceding sibling input via css3.

Answer (score -1):

Like @ninty9notout said, you can't use the sibling selector to get a preceding selector, only the following one. So alternatively, you could:

```
div label { display: none; }
```

Comment: This isn't useful, as it's the input I can't select, not the label. I also only want to select this using CSS3, so older browsers (IE) are still usable without a pile of hacks.